Getting Georeferencer target CRS with PyQGIS
According to the C++ code in qgsgeorefmainwindow.cpp I tried to retrieve the Georeferencer target CRS with PyQGIS using QgsSettings().value("/Plugin-GeoReferencer/targetsrs") but unfortunately this failed (QGIS 3.40.1 Windows).
QgsSettings settings;
// default to last used target CRS
QString targetCRSString = settings.value( QStringLiteral( "/Plugin-GeoReferencer/targetsrs" ) ).toString();
mTargetCrs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem( targetCRSString );

How can I obtain the correct value here?

It looks like bug: such setting is never saved in the QGIS.ini file.
Please create an issue report at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues.

That's exactly what I found out too, just needed a confirmation. Do you know if there is a workaround to get the data directly from QgsTransformSettingsDialog?

I've submitted a fix for such issue: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/59903.

many thanks for the quick help!
